# mod_rewrite in .htaccess issues

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have sniffed through quite a few postings about mod_rewrite this turned out more complex than I was expecting.

What I am trying to do is the following.
I have 10 cities with events, and each city should have their own "directory" such as:
site.com/toronto/
site.com/chicago/

The events could have up to 3 sub levels such as

site.com/toronto/musiccamp/sub18

site.com/chicago/bootcamp

And I need these URLs mapped to the page

site.com/camps/index.php?city=toronto&type=musiccamp&ages=sub18

site.com/camps/index.php?city=chicago&type=bootcamp

Other directories, such as 
site.com/about - site.com/help etc
should NOT be rewritten.

This has to be within an .htaccess file.

So far I got this going (in godaddy servers)

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php?option1=$1 [L]
```

However I am unable to pass the options to index.php... they are always null...

Answer (score 1):

In the end, this is what worked best in my case

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php?option1=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

That way any path that does not exist will get rewriten to the /test/index.php file and can be handled from there.

Passing the REQUEST_URI allows me to build N level deep and have the index.php file parse it out.

Hope this helps someone.